# undefined is not a function ('evaluating '_reactNativeRouterFlux...)

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm using [`react-native-router-flux`](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux) for navigation in ReactJS.
This is how I define scenes in my **Router.js** file

```
import { Scene, Router, Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';
    const RouterComponent = () => {
      return (
        <Router>
          <Scene key="myMainScene">
            <Scene key="chooseLevel" component={ChooseLevel} title="Select a level" />
            <Scene key="quizPage" component={QuizPage} title="" />
          </Scene>
        </Router>
      );
    };
```

And this is my action creator :

```
import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';
    export const levelSelected = (levelNumber) => {
        return (dispatch) => {
            dispatch({type: LEVEL_SELECTED, payload: levelNumber});
            Actions.quizPage({ type: 'levelNumber' });
        };  
    };
```

In my action creator I'm trying to redirect user to another page (QuizPage component) but when I try the app on the device I get the red screen with this error message:

```
 undefined is not a function ('evaluating '_reactNativeRouterFlux.Actions.quizPage({type:'levelNumber'})')
```

Comment: Im not familiar with this library but could it be that you didnt define a parameter 'type' to quiz page and that's why it wont recognize this page?

Comment: No, it gives me the same error even if I don't pass any parameters like this: Actions.quizPage();

Comment: I think `Actions` wont have function `quizPage`

Comment: I think you need to define your Scene inside of the Actions, like in the documentation :
const scenes = Actions.create(
  <Scene key="root">
    <Scene key="login" component={Login} title="Login"/>
    <Scene key="register" component={Register} title="Register"/>
    <Scene key="home" component={Home}/>
  </Scene>
);